# Crypto++ HexEncoder not working consistently

Tags: c++, crypto++

Here's my code

```
#include <cryptopp/hex.h>

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void hexlify(CryptoPP::byte* bytes, std::string &hex_string, size_t size)
{
    CryptoPP::StringSource ss(bytes, size, true, new CryptoPP::HexEncoder(new CryptoPP::StringSink(hex_string)));
}

void unhexlify(std::string hex_string, CryptoPP::byte* &bytes)
{
    std::string decoded;

    CryptoPP::StringSource ss(hex_string, true, new CryptoPP::HexDecoder(new CryptoPP::StringSink(decoded)));

    std::cout << decoded + "\n"; // For testing
    bytes = (CryptoPP::byte*)decoded.data();
}

int main()
{
    std::string seed = "BF0F3123B21A60E5AB7615AD06EA16A2BD44D84CED4DCC10AA0413127F87DC60";
    std::cout << "\n" + seed + "\n";

    CryptoPP::byte* b;
    unhexlify(seed, b);

    std::string s;
    hexlify(b, s, 32);

    std::cout << s;
    std::cout << "\n\n";
}
```

It should take the 32-byte, 64-character hex string `seed`, print it, convert it into bytes, then convert it back into a hex string (`s`) and print it. I also have it print the decoded string in the `unhexlify` function.

My expectation is for the output to look like this:

```
BF0F3123B21A60E5AB7615AD06EA16A2BD44D84CED4DCC10AA0413127F87DC60
?1#?`?v????D?L?M????`
BF0F3123B21A60E5AB7615AD06EA16A2BD44D84CED4DCC10AA0413127F87DC60
```

The first line (`seed`) and the third line (`s`, the seed converted into bytes and back) should be the same. And very rarely, that's exactly what happens. However, most of the time the first and third lines are completely different.

What's weird is that I made zero changes to the code, and I didn't even recompile it. But every time I run the executable, it says something different. What's even weirder is that the third line is different every time I run it. Again, it happens even though I'm running the same executable without changing the code or recompiling. Here are the outputs from 5 runs:

```
BF0F3123B21A60E5AB7615AD06EA16A2BD44D84CED4DCC10AA0413127F87DC60
?1#?`?v????D?L?M????`
205BC0AE8B7F0000AB7615AD06EA16A2889A960301000000189C960301000000
```

```
BF0F3123B21A60E5AB7615AD06EA16A2BD44D84CED4DCC10AA0413127F87DC60
?1#?`?v????D?L?M????`
205B40C2B87F0000AB7615AD06EA16A288FA9B060100000018FC9B0601000000
```

```
BF0F3123B21A60E5AB7615AD06EA16A2BD44D84CED4DCC10AA0413127F87DC60
?1#?`?v????D?L?M????`
205BC07DA67F0000AB7615AD06EA16A2885A6C0B01000000185C6C0B01000000
```

```
BF0F3123B21A60E5AB7615AD06EA16A2BD44D84CED4DCC10AA0413127F87DC60
?1#?`?v????D?L?M????`
205BC06EB47F0000AB7615AD06EA16A288DAAE090100000018DCAE0901000000
```

```
BF0F3123B21A60E5AB7615AD06EA16A2BD44D84CED4DCC10AA0413127F87DC60
?1#?`?v????D?L?M????`
205BC0F9EB7F0000AB7615AD06EA16A288DAF5010100000018DCF50101000000
```

The second line is the same every time, so I know the problem is with the `hexlify` function and/or the Crypto++ HexEncoder. Also, the section `AB7615AD06EA16A2` always matches in both `seed` and `s`. The section that does match goes from the 17th character to the 32nd character. That always happens for every seed I try. But everything else is usually different.

I don't understand why it's not encoding the bytes into a hex string properly. And I don't understand why it rarely does work even if I made no changes to the code. And I especially don't understand how the output can be different every time I run the same compiled code. What is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void unhexlify(std::string hex_string, CryptoPP::byte* &bytes)
{
    std::string decoded;

    CryptoPP::StringSource ss(hex_string, true, new CryptoPP::HexDecoder(new CryptoPP::StringSink(decoded)));

    std::cout << decoded + "\n"; // For testing
    bytes = (CryptoPP::byte*)decoded.data();  // <--
}
```

You return the pointer to the buffer owned by the local variable `decoded` that dies after function exit. You get the undefined behavior with following passing the dangling pointer to `hexlify`. To fix the issue return string from `std::string unhexlify(std::string hex_string)` and call `hexlify(bytes.data(), s. bytes.size())`.

Answer (score 1):

This function looks suspicious:

```
void unhexlify(std::string hex_string, CryptoPP::byte* &bytes)
{
    std::string decoded;
    // stuff added to decoded, maybe...
    bytes = (CryptoPP::byte*)decoded.data();
}
```

`decoded` is a local variable that is destroyed as the function exits, but you're making `bytes` point to the internal data of it, causing a dangling pointer (which is undefined behavior, and differing output is explained by that.)

You should just return decoded as the return value (by value), and store it on the caller's stack.  Then set bytes to its data after this function returns in the calling code.